# iTunes Music Store Link Maker — how to search from within my app?

Tags: iphone, itunes, itunes-store

I'm writing a music reference app and for each album (pulled from last.fm) would like to link to the ITMS (if the album is in the store).

iTunes link maker web tool http://apple.com/itunes/linkmaker/ is great for getting links for a known album but I need to access it programatically from within my app.

This [NSLog blogpost](http://nslog.com/2003/04/29/itms_links) which is from 2003 but was [referenced more recently in another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893604/how-to-link-to-the-itunes-store-from-iphone-app/893607#893607) seems to offer the only solution I've come across so far, suggesting to submit a query to:

> phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/advancedSearchResults?
>
> Put "itms://" before it and the link will work in iTunes, put "http://" before it and the link will work in Camino (Safari sometimes spits back a malformed XML error).
>
> The tags that are of importance are as follows:
>
> - songTerm - song title
> - artistTerm - artist name
> - albumTerm - album name
> - composerTerm - composer name
> - term - all fields

The suggestion is that would using http:// rather than itms:// the server will return an XML document of results instead of opening iTunes but either way I am sent directly to iTunes.

Is it possible to get back a list of results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using LinkMaker to get iTunes details about song I am playing.
For that, I found that LinkMaker is able to return json data and also 1 result at a time.

I am using this url to perfom my query :

> http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/itmsSearch?lang=1&output=json&country=%@&term=%@&media=%@&limit=1"

Here are parameters you need to give :

```
> country : store country term : could
> contains artist name, song name, album
> media : music
```

For exemple, if you want to have details for a song called "One" by "U2" here is the correct URL :

http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/itmsSearch?lang=1&output=json&country=US&term=U2%20one&media=music&limit=1

Then you will receive json data like this :

```
{
 "resultCount":1,
 "results": [
{"wrapperType":"track", "mediaType":"song", "artistName":"U2", "itemParentName":"Achtung Baby", "itemParentCensoredName":"Achtung Baby", "itemCensoredName":"One", "itemName":"One", "artistLinkUrl":"http://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/u2/id78500?uo=4", "artworkUrl60":"http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/009/Features/32/9a/60/dj.mfynlttx.60x60-50.jpg", "artworkUrl100":"http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/009/Features/32/9a/60/dj.mfynlttx.100x100-75.jpg", "country":"USA", "currency":"USD", "discCount":1, "discNumber":1, "itemExplicitness":"notExplicit", "itemLinkUrl":"http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/one/id368713?i=368617&uo=4", "itemPrice":"1.29000", "itemParentExplicitness":"notExplicit", "itemParentLinkUrl":"http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/one/id368713?i=368617&uo=4", "itemParentPrice":"9.99000", "previewUrl":"http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/019/Music/b6/8c/c5/mzm.epegonxg.aac.p.m4a", "primaryGenreName":"Rock", "trackCount":12, "trackNumber":3, "trackTime":276042}]
}
```

You need then to decode these JSON data.

```
NSDictionary *jsonResultsParsed = [jsonResults JSONValue];
```

And finally get what you want :

```
NSDictionary *songDetailsDict = [[jsonResultsParsed objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

If you want to determine user's country you will need to determine its country using its locale, here is the code I am using :

```
- (NSString *)getUserCountry
{
    NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    return [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Thierry

Edit: Finally a doc is available:

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

Comment: Thanks for this usage example. Out of curiosity, are you using the US store always in your app or do you switch depending on user?

Answer (score 0):

This document for [iTunes Store Web Service Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunesaffiliates/API/AffiliatesSearch2.1.pdf) (pdf), although old and incomplete, seems to be the way to accomplish this.

It's a painful experience setting this up though, as has been every other part of the affiliate programme.